# How to insert Canonical which is gone from <head>?

Tags: wordpress, canonical-link

When I go to `<head>` and search canonical it doesn't display any more. I removed it months ago to do a temp fix on a different issue but now I'm ready to add it back in...not sure where I should add it (prob in head section) and I don't know what code specifically to put in.

Bonus Round:
Put in Canonical but exclude /user/* to canonicalise back to /user/

My domain: Pixelsmithstudios
CMS: Wordpress Latest (10 Feb 2017)

Comment: I have yoast installed (but that canonical is also not working since I take it uses the Wordpress default canonical rule)